# Keycloak conditional OTP not working as per rules

Tags: java, keycloak

I am using Keycloak (4.1.0.Final). I have created a custom Authentication flow in which a conditional OTP Form has been configured. The form has been configured to skip OTP for a role. The selected role is client role.

Even after the role has been assigned, user is still asked to enter OTP. The default fallback option has been set to skip.

Please suggest what can be done

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the user has OTP enabled.

If the user has OTP enabled then he will be asked for an OTP independent of the conditional OTP setting.

The conditional OTP setting is only used to determine if the user must use OTP.

Besides this every user can enable OTP independent of the conditional OTP setting to secure his/her account.

Comment: Hi @uwe-plonus
Thanks for your reply. I upgraded to keycloak 4.8.6 and there is now a different authentication mechanism that we are employing (no OTP step). Hence, I won't able to verify these steps now. Thanks once again for your time.

Comment: @CuriousMind I work with keycloak 6.0.1 and stumbled myself over this...